# How to uninstall Proxychains.conf file on Kali Linux and reinstall

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, data-recovery, proxy

Hello I am a beginner in Ethical Hacking using Kali Linux as an OS.
I have just messed up my proxychains.conf file located on my /etc/ folder while trying to edit it with nano editor.

I want to know how to uninstall and reinstall the file so i could get a new content of the file back.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the configuration file located in /etc and then have apt regenerate it:

```
rm -f /etc/proxychains.conf
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall proxychains
```

This commads should be run as root, with `sudo` in front of them.

Comment: I would say this is a good answer except that I would mv that /etc/proxychains.conf to a safe place instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found the solution; try running these commands:

```
apt-get purge proxychains
apt-get purge --auto-remove proxychains
```

and after that install it again:

```
apt-get install proxychains
```

If you're not running Kali as root add `sudo` before each command.